# Can i expect anything from Windows-API's Sleep function?

Tags: c++, windows, sleep, frame-rate, msdn

I was trying to make a simple graphics program for Windows (my machine has windows 10) in CPP, and I'm struggling to lock the frame rate.

Here's simple illustration of my problem:

```
inline LARGE_INTEGER
get_wall_clock()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER result;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&result);
    return result;
}

static LARGE_INTEGER frequency;

inline float
get_seconds_elapsed(LARGE_INTEGER begin, LARGE_INTEGER end)
{
    return (float)(end.QuadPart - begin.QuadPart) / (float)frequency.QuadPart;
}

int main()
{
    bool can_sleep = (timeBeginPeriod(1) == TIMERR_NOERROR);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    int target_HZ = 60;
    float target_seconds_per_frame = 1.0f / (float)target_HZ;
    LARGE_INTEGER last_counter = get_wall_clock();
    while(true)
    {
        do_something();

        LARGE_INTEGER end_frame = get_wall_clock();
        float seconds_of_work = get_seconds_elapsed(last_counter, end_frame);
        float seconds_of_frame = seconds_of_work;
        if(seconds_of_work < target_seconds_per_frame)
        {
            if(can_sleep)
            {
                int ms_to_sleep = (int)(1000.0f * (target_seconds_per_frame - seconds_of_work));
                if(ms_to_sleep)
                {
                    Sleep(ms_to_sleep);
                }
            }
            float frame_duration = get_seconds_elapsed(last_counter, get_wall_clock());
            Assert(frame_duration < target_seconds_per_frame);
            while(seconds_of_frame < target_seconds_per_frame)
                seconds_of_frame = get_seconds_elapsed(last_counter, get_wall_clock());
        }
        last_counter = get_wall_clock();
    }
    timeEndPeriod(1);
}
```

My problem is that the assertion on:

```
Assert(frame_duration < target_seconds_per_frame);
```

is almost always firing.

I tried to make some adjustments to the amount of mili-seconds of sleep, even made it so it will sleep for only 90% of the mili-seconds needed - but it didn't seems to help.

But the real weird thing is the following... when i tried to measure the time the Sleep function actually slept for, in the following method:

```
LARGE_INTEGER sleep_start = get_wall_clock();
Sleep(ms_to_sleep);
float seconds_slept = get_seconds_elapsed(sleep_start, get_wall_clock());
```

i found out that it sometimes sleep for **waaayyy** more than the mili-seconds requested. it not uncommon to see a different of 10-20 mili-seconds (i had a time when `ms_to_sleep` was 12 and it actually slept for over 30 mili-seconds).

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here?
I know that according to the documentation Sleep is not guaranteed to sleep for the time requested, but i thought that timeBeginPeriod + the flooring of the `ms_to_sleep` would have cover that...

Is there any other way to wait reliably for the frame to end (other than just looping)?

Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here?

Frankly, yes. You didn't read the manual. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep):

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. If you specify 0 milliseconds, the thread will relinquish the remainder of its time slice but remain ready. **Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately.** Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses. For more information, see Scheduling Priorities.

`Sleep` isn't made to sleep for exactly the time you asked for.

Comment: Oh, even when after I've checked that beginTimePeriod(1)'s call has been successful?

Comment: also - can i expect from it for **some** level of accuracy?

Comment: @ItzikShneorson the resolution of the clock comes on top of the effect I quoted in the answer

Comment: @ItzikShneorson I don't know any details in windows, but when a thread continues is up to the scheduler and typically you have little control over that.

Comment: mmm... but anyway: i thought that 10-20 ms (probably around 26,843,540 processor's cycles) is a long enough period...